# correctness of URL

Tags: plugins, filters, urls

if I call shortcode in some page, then this address is correct?

```
http://mypage.com/recipes_page/?strona=2
```

Wordpress automatically add "/".

As far as I remember, it has always been:

```
http://mypage.com/recipes_page.php?strona=2?filter=1
```

All work's but is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the accepted answer to this question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/81252/is-a-trailing-slash-appropriate-before-url-parameters

tl;dr Either way is correct, but consistency in the result is the key to best SEO practices, because with/without is a different URL.

If you don't want the trailing slash (or you do), you can change it in your Admin, Permalinks screen.